# rviz: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext

Tags: ros, rviz, opengl, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to run "rosrun rviz rviz" i get this output :

```
[ INFO] [1306327198.635135186]: Loading general config from [/home/rajat/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1306327198.650256875]: Loading display config from [/home/rajat/.rviz/display_config]
[ERROR] [1306327199.295138649]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.0/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
```

After wasting more than 5 hours on this , i still can't figure out the solution. :( . Please help .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10056/rviz:-ogre-exception(3:renderingapiexception):-unable-to-create-a-suitable-glxcontext-in-glxcontext/) by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-06-03**:
Did you ever solve your problem?

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-12-20**:
Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it working , i guess this is some issue with the video card drive . i was using ubnutu in a virtual machine inside windows , but now i installed it as a separate operating system along with the windows , and installed everything again . and everything seems to work fine now :).
i know this is not the solution , but if you have the same case give this method a try .

---

Originally posted by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) with karma: 175 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-15**:
Actually it is the solution. 3D and virtual machines don't work well together and rviz/OGRE makes heavy use of 3D features.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why this would happen but my best guess is that you don't have MESA available.

You can test this by running `glxinfo` which should give you a bunch of information about the OpenGL renderers available whether through hardware or software.

If this is empty or fails to even run as well, then you'll need to install Mesa, GLX, and/or hardware drivers for your video card.

You can try `glxgears` as well to prove your OpenGL rendering hardware/software pipeline is working.

Also a shallow google search brings up this: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=51227&start=0 where someone seemed to have the same problem because their X server GLX/DRI/OpenGL settings were messed up somehow.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I met the same problem. And I solved it by installing OpenGL library with an old version of Nvidia driver installer. For Ubuntu 16.04, I use 384.69

In the container, this command works:

nvidia-installer.run -a -N --ui=none --no-kernel-module

---

Originally posted by [astro](https://answers.ros.org/users/49425/astro/) with karma: 11 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and it solved itself after just rebooting my PC. I guess there was an update in the background that needed a reboot or something.

---

Originally posted by [Iñigo moreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/34685/i%C3%B1igo-moreno/) with karma: 21 on 2021-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [m.sanchez.rico](https://answers.ros.org/users/23943/m.sanchez.rico/) on 2023-04-11**:
Same issue, It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution for me was to reboot my machine (Ubuntu 20).

I was getting this error when running `nvidia-smi`:

> Failed to initialize NVML:
> Driver/library version mismatch

The NVML issue was what was causing the `OGRE EXCEPTION` error

---

Originally posted by [jstm](https://answers.ros.org/users/35977/jstm/) with karma: 21 on 2022-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1